# Add custom certificate in trust store

Tags: android, ssl, android-security

I have one API to be integrate in android app. API is using two-way ssl handshake.
I need to add the server certificate in my app TrustStore and a jks file in the Keystore to authenticate the connection handshake.

I have searched a alot on stackoverflow but not satisfy with any of the answers.

Can anyone give some reference or solution regarding my issue.

**EDIT**

I'm using Http implementation to establish the connection.

```
public static SSLContext getSSLContext(Context context){

        try {

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream input_ca_main = new BufferedInputStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.main));

            Certificate ca_main;

            ca_main = cf.generateCertificate(input_ca_main);

            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca_main).getSubjectDN());

            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca_main", ca_main);

            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslcontext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            return sslcontext;

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is what i have used to include the certificates in the request. But after reading the concept of two-way ssl, i found out that the server certificate must be in our truststore.

Comment: what resources have you looked up and why do they not satisy your requirements?

Comment: All answers i have looked up till are used to load thecertificates from the trust store.

Comment: Do you want to add your server provided certificate to your request? What library are you using for consuming APIs (network connection)? volley or retrofit? Need to be more specific when you ask for guidance..

Comment: Im Using Http implementation. i need to add the server ceritficate into my trust store so that the trusted connection will be established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for a server certificate to be added to your trusted certificates in your device. I am afraid you have to follow what you have seen in other examples using a trust store.

If you are looking for a way to add certificate to your request, try the following code(assuming you use volley):

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); // this will be your certificate files extension.
            keyStore.load(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64Helper.decodeIntoByteArray(YOUR_CERTIFICATE_HERE),
                   YOUR_CERT_PASSWORD_HERE);

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, YOUR_CERT_PASSWORD);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            HurlStack hurlStack = new HurlStack(null, sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(EMISMobileApplication.getInstance().getAppContext(), hurlStack);
```

Then use this request queue to connect back to your server.

Comment: but i need to put the certificate in TrustStore.

Comment: I shall try this code and see if it establish the connection.

Comment: I have tried this code. i'm IOException of wrong version of key store

Comment: Looks like your are trying to add your server certificate to your local truststore.. then As I have said try other examples...https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: I was able to store the certification with reference to this answer, Thanks Buddy.

Comment: Happy I could help you Buddy.. ! :)